# How do I Add an entity and then return the newly created entity with its loaded relations in entity framework core?

Tags: c#, orm, entity-framework-core

When I am retrieving an existing model I can do the following to return the model and its related entities:

```
db.Pets
.Include(_ => _.BestFriend.Species.Diet)
.Include(_ => _.BestFriend.Hobbies)
.Include(_ => _.Hobbies)
.FirstOrDefaultAsync(_ => _.PetName == "Spot");
```

Now when I add a pet to the pet db I would like to also return the loaded relations and nested relations same as when i query for an existing pet from the db.

```
db.pets.Add(newPet)  ...load relations and return new record
---------------------------------------- 
// Whats the equivalent of the below when adding a record?
.Include(_ => _.BestFriend.Species.Diet)
.Include(_ => _.BestFriend.Hobbies)
.Include(_ => _.Hobbies)
```

I could of course add the new pet and then call the get method to load the newly created animal with its relations.

So my question is how do I add a new record and load its relations fluently in entity framework core? or is this not possible?

I feel like this is possible and should be easy, but not sure what I am missing.

Comment: You cannot just add Pet and expect the relations to be added automagically. You need to add the relations yourself.

Comment: The relations are specified in the pet object. i.e. When I create the  pet object i have a field for the best friend id and the relations are all setup.

Comment: Saving the new entity only returns the saved entity, not it's related entities. Either reload the entity with the related entities from the database, or explicitly load the related entities. See the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit.